# Get the URL from this output of Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

How can I get the URL from this output of Selenium in Python?

```
<div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; background-position: 0px 0px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 480px; height: 672.172px; float: left; background-size: 1054px 1476px; display: none; border: 0px solid rgb(136, 136, 136); background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://photo.venus.com/im/19230307.jpg?preset=zoom&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
```

I got the above output from the following command line:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('zoomWindowContainer')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, get style atribute by:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('zoomWindow')
style = div.get_attribute("style") # str
```

Then, using regex to find url from style:

```
import re
urls = re.findall(r"https?://.+\.jpg", style) # list
print (urls[0])
```